# Why am I able to use MessageUI without a framework reference?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

In my Swift 2 project, targeting iOS 9.2 and above, in Xcode 8.2.1, I have code that shows the mail-compose screen like so:

```
if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {

    let composeMailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composeMailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    composeMailVC.setSubject("Test")
    // etc
}
```

Originally I had a reference to the `MessageUI.framework` in my project properties, but after removing the framework reference and cleaning the project, it still builds fine and when I run the code on my device the mail compose window still appears and seems fully functional.

I cannot find any explicit references to `MessageUI.framework` in the raw text of my `.xcodeproj` file, nor is there anything in my Objective-C bridging header.

I know that Swift does make some implicit framework references, but I couldn't find anything that suggests `MessageUI.framework` is one of them.

Curiously when I jump to the definition of `MFMailComposeViewController` XCode shows it in the `MessageUI` module.

Comment: Do you have the `import MessageUI` statement at the top of your swift file?

Comment: @chengsam Yes, I have `import MessageUI` and `import Foundation` at the top of the file that uses `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Comment: The `import` statement linked the `MessageUI` framework for you behind the scene. For a more detailed description, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425371/linked-frameworks-and-libraries-in-swift-project).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler automatically added the frame work in given its previous direction - IE. Import.